# select within either array or object

Tags: json, types, filtering, jq, jtc

Given these three documents...

One with a Statement object:

```
{
    "PolicyVersion": {
        "CreateDate": "2017-07-13T18:59:21Z", 
        "VersionId": "v2", 
        "Document": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
            "Statement": {
                "Action": "*", 
                "Resource": "*", 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        }, 
        "IsDefaultVersion": true
    }
}
```

...and one with a Statement array:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

...and one with a Statement nested within the full document:

```
{
    "PolicyVersion": {
        "CreateDate": "2017-07-13T18:59:21Z", 
        "VersionId": "v2", 
        "Document": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "*", 
                    "Resource": "*", 
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "IsDefaultVersion": true
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to have a single command to select when `.Action == '*'` and `.Resource == '*'` exist within the Statement, whether it's an array, an object, and where it's nested?

For example, I'm scanning through thousands of documents where the only difference is the Statement may be an object or an array.

Of course something like: `jq '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[] | select((.Action == "*") and .Resource == "*")` works for an array and `jq '.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement | select((.Action == "*") and .Resource == "*")` works for when it's not an array but I'd like to acheive this in one command.

I've tried a few things around `select` like:

`jq '.PolicyVersion.Document | select((.Statement[] | select((.Action == "*") and .Resource == "*") or select((.Statement[] | select((.Action == "*") and .Resource == "*")'`

which returns nothing, and:

`jq '.PolicyVersion.Document | select((.Statement[] | select((.Action == "*") and .Resource == "*") or select((.Statement | select((.Action == "*") and .Resource == "*")'`

which returns a unix shell quoting error.

Comment: for your consideration, the same JSON query could be achieved using an _alternative_ unix _walk-path_ utility _jtc_: **`<file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<*>[-1][Resource]:<*>[^0]'`**. If you like I can elaborate in a separate answer on the tool usage (PS. I'm a developer of the tool) .

Comment: Thanks for spreading the knowledge, @Dmitry :) Always appreciate alternatives and learning different ways.

Comment: btw, in the above example the whole document is selected (I might misunderstood the question), in the answer below, I'll elaborate how to select only the record in `Statement ` containing `Action` and `Resource` if both are `"*"`. Let me know if the ask meant different.

Comment: I also found a lambda function using `jmespath` that achieves it using the following: `if jmespath.search('PolicyVersion.Document.Statement[?Effect == \'Allow\' && contains(Resource, \'*\') && contains (Action, \'*\')]', policy_version):` thought I'd share here just as another possible approach/solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be more generic than you need, or maybe too generic, so feel free to season to taste:

```
..
| objects
| select(.Statement)
| .Statement
| if type == "array" then .[] else . end
| select(.Action == "*" and .Resource == "*")
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Works for all use cases I can think of/have seen so far (the three I included in my final OP). If you could, would you mind breaking down how this is working? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which is quite specific to this particular case:

```
.PolicyVersion.Document.Statement
| ..
| select(type == "object" and .Action == "*" and .Resource == "*")
```

Comment: That does work, thank you. I have updated my question as it posted before I was finished adding my use case examples. Might be another question but I'm looking to also get this working if the Statement is at the document root and not nested as well.

Comment: @TryTryAgain Refer to peak's answer for that

Answer (score 2):

With the OP's permission, let me show here how achieve the same JSON query using a *walk-path* unix utility [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc). However, instead of explaining the *walk-path*, I'll show how to build it.

My understanding of the question: validate JSON documents so that if there's anywhere in the document an entry with the label `Statement` which contains elements `"Action": "*"` and `"Resource": "*"`, then print the whole record containing those elements, otherwise don't (i.e. leave a blank output)

1. Let's begin with finding a JSON entry with the label `Statement` recursively (a notation for a recursive search is `<..>`, suffix `l` instructs to search *labels* only), so it can be anywhere in the JSON document (I'll be using first JSON example):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l'
[
   {
      "Action": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
   }
]
bash $
```

2. Once `Statement` record is found, we need to see if there's a record `"*"` somewhere in the found entry ***attached*** to the label `"Action"` (use a recursive search again but restrict the search only to entries with `Action` label - a.k.a. *scoped search*):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<*>'
"*"
bash $
```

3. Now we need to see if there's a sibling (`"Resource": "*"`) to the found entry. For that let's step up one level in the JSON tree (a.k.a address a parent):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<*>[-1]'
{
   "Action": "*",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "*"
}
bash $
```

and then use a *non-recursive* scoped search (a *non-recursive* search notation is `>..<`):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<*>[-1][Resource]:>*<'
"*"
bash $
```

4. Finally, to select the record, let's address again a parent of the last found/walked entry:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<*>[-1][Resource]:>*<[-1]'
{
   "Action": "*",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "*"
}
bash $
```

The above *walk-path* will facilitate required JSON query for all JSON documents (whether `Statement` is nested or not, or whether `Action` and `Resource` records (deeply) enlisted in the array or not - but they must remain siblings).
If any of the walk lexemes fails, then the whole output will be blank:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<blah>[-1][Resource]:>*<[-1]' 
bash $
```

Finally, `jtc` is times faster when reading from file (instead of `stdin`), for performance reasons it's best to use it passing file as an argument:

```
jtc -w'<Statement>l[Action]:<*>[-1][Resource]:>*<[-1]' file.json
```

PS> I'm the creator of the [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) unix utility for JSON processing